# ¿Como realizar conexiones múltiples de bases de datos en Laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, mongodb

Tengo un proyecto de una red social la cual tiene una base de datos en mysql, pero quiero que la tabla de publicaciones (post) se guarde en mongodb y las de mas tablas en mysql, como puedo hacerle para que funcionen al mismo tiempo.

Answer (score 1):

No conozco mucho de Laravel, pero el problema usualmente tiene la misma solución en diferentes lenguajes/tecnologías.

Crea tus clases de acceso a datos hacia tus tablas que trabajen con la conexión a MySQL para todas, excepto en la clase que trabaja con Post, esta clase que se conecte a MongoDB (o lo que necesites) y así desacoplas a los clientes de estas clases con la fuente de datos real que utilizas.

Answer (score 1):

En este articulo hay un ejemplo de como hacer múltiples conexiones en laravel

[Multiple DB Connections in Laravel](http://fideloper.com/laravel-multiple-database-connections)